# Python equivalent of Sinatra

Tags: python, model-view-controller, sinatra, web.py

I know that many people use Sinatra when programming webapps in Ruby because they don't want their framework to get in the way by forcing them to use MVC.

Is there something similar in Python? I'm looking for a framework which provides the glue between Python and the web, and not much more. I've looked at Web.py, but it doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for.

**EDIT:** Instead of just linking to random frameworks, please also say how they compare to the others, and what special features they have.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at the [Flask microframework](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Answer (score 13):

There are several micro web frameworks. I personally like [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)

A good [overview list of options exist here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks).